# VB3 decompiler?

Tags: windows-7, reverse-engineering, decompiling

Someone I used to work for emailed me out of the blue and said they want me to update a VB3 (!!!) program I wrote for them because customers are reporting having problems running it under Windows 7.  They have lost the source code (natch).  Is there a decompiler for VB3?

Comment: Dangit. Now I have to pick my jaw up off the floor for the second time today! Good luck with this! :)

Comment: I assume you also lost the source code? :)

Comment: I wrote it for Windows 3.1... apparently it had no problems with Windows 95, 98, ME, or XP... I wonder why suddenly Windows 7... maybe something with 64 bit?

Comment: Windows 3.1? And they want support after almost 20 years?

Comment: @casablanca, it must be some *awesome* software. "I'll have what she's having."

Comment: Just in case they missed the obvious: try running it in compatibility mode for 9x...

Comment: It was also the first Windows program I ever wrote... I don't think it was anything that amazing... it's just that it's for a limited market without much competition

Comment: Sounds like it might be the first Windows program _anyone_ ever wrote.  Seriously, VB3?  Could they be experiencing a Y1K problem?

Comment: @Larry, they're experiencing a poor planning problem, same as when they agreed to rewrite products for Windows only after the DOS products started tanking in sales... to be fair, it's a tiny company

Comment: @JoelFan: I'm only joking.  The most viewed question I have asked on StackOverflow was about converting a Delphi 3 application to Delphi 2010 when my client reappeared after 10 years wanting to incorporate scanning and emailing and to go paperless.  Fortunately, I had kept the original Win98 development machine and copies of the source code.

Comment: Pardon my rant but isn't losing the source code to your own product pretty gross incompetence... i mean sheesh...

Comment: I'm still maintaining a VB3 program. Besides of not running at all in 64bits, Win7 add several security measures that bring problems (i.e. SendKeys don't work anymore). XP it's the last reliable OS to run them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the later versions which used native code and are generally not reliably decompilable, VB3 (and, I think, VB4) could be usually decompiled to almost original code. The keywords you need to search for are "DoDi VB3 decompiler" or "vb3dis". [Here's](http://www.woodmann.com/crackz/Tools.htm) a page that seems to have a copy.

Answer (score 5):

For decompiling VB "**DoDi VB3 decompiler**" is the best tool available. The results are pretty good.

However the original is anno 1997. VB3 is 16 bit code only + still some bugs + no source code. These makes that tool hard to get running on windows beyond Windows XP and limits it's use.

DoDi's VBDIS3 it self is also written in VB3 - so about 10 years later just for fun I cracked it to make the decompiler to decompile it self.
... and ported it to VB6!
So now you've the source code !!! :D

... and it's 32 Bit code + some bugfixes and improvements to the original:

**DoDi's Visual Basic 3 Decompiler [Reloaded]**:

http://vbdis4.angelfire.com

Screenshoot:
[image: DoDi's Visual Basic 3 Decompiler [Reloaded]]

---

in case that website get lost Google for
'**VBDIS3.67e_Reloaded_Rev3_DoDi_s_VB3Decompiler.7z**'
or try the internet archive

http://web.archive.org/web/20090301170633/http://vbdis4.angelfire.com

Answer (score 4):

I remember looking for Visual Basic decompilers/disassemblers a long time ago to no avail. There may be things out there now though. The most I could come up with was PE Explorer: http://www.heaventools.com/overview.htm

Have you suggested running your application under Windows Compatibility mode: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/316-compatibility-mode.html

Edit: Further Googling: http://www.w7forums.com/visual-basic-3-0-compatible-64-bit-version-t5146.html

> I maintain legacy 16-bit VB3 software
>   that is compatible with Windows 7 and
>   have done a lot of research in this
>   area.
>
> 16-bit applications will not natively
>   run in Windows 7 64-bit full stop.
>   This is because when a 64-bit capable
>   CPU is started in 64-bit mode, it
>   cannot change into 'real mode' (the
>   mode used by 16-bit applications)
>   without a hard reset. If a processor
>   is in 32-bit mode, it can swap between
>   real mode and protected mode at will.
>
> The only workaround here is a virtual
>   machine- Windows 7 comes with a free
>   version of Windows XP which is usable
>   inside a custom version of Microsoft
>   Virtual PC. Google for "Windows 7
>   Virtual XP Mode". Once your copy of
>   Windows 7 has been validated as
>   authentic, it will allow you to
>   download Virtual PC and the XP Image.
>
> It's definitely not a pretty solution,
>   but the only option for my customers
>   who have gone ahead and bought a
>   64-bit OS without checking to see if
>   their installed software is 64-bit
>   compatible.

Comment: It may work in Windows Compatibility mode, but I'm guessing that would hurt sales

Comment: @JoelFan, why would that hurt sales? My understanding is that compatibility mode is relatively seamless.

Comment: @JoelFan: You're still selling 20 year old software?

Comment: @JoelFan, why would it hurt sales?  Are you kidding?  Customer buys product. Customer installs product.  Product does not work. Customer returns product.  Sales go boom.

Comment: @Travis, I'm not selling it... my former employer is.

Comment: @JoelFan, your little timeline above has an assumption ('Product does not work') - I think what the answers were getting at was that hopefully, with the Compatibility box, the product _would_ work. That may not be the case now, seeing abrereton's update.

Comment: @paxdiablo, the customer is not going to know about compatibility mode or even if they do, they are not going to think it's worth it.  This is not a business-critical app, it's a consumer app sold in shrink-wrapped boxes.  It doesn't take much to generate a return in that market.

Comment: @JoelFan, this sort of thing is well established. I've had (older) games that I've bought that needed something downloaded from the internet to get them to work. Better, this is something that the installer should do. In other words, the company should either get someone to redo the installer to flag the executable as requires-compat-mode or, at a minimum, add a flash device or something with a little exe that does that for the customer. Put that device with instructions (or just instructions on how to get the updates from the web, if the company is a tightwad) into the new packages.

Comment: But there's no point discussing those options if the thing won't even run in compat mode. I agree that asking the customers to run Virtual PC is probably too much. Maybe the company should just ensure the doco says supported platforms stop at XP. Then, if they want more customers, they have to invest in upgrading the software. You can only milk a dead cow for so long :-)

Answer (score 2):

Really? VB3, if it runs fine in XP, should be okay in the Windows compatibility box.

What I would do is to say that you couldn't find anything suitable (which is almost certainly true) but that you may be able to fix their problem for a moderate fee. Then, hopefully it's just a matter of setting a flag on the application (you may want to check this first to ensure it won't be too much work).

Money for Jam.

The other option is that you can offer to rewrite it for them in a more modern setting, using your vast knowledge of the application.

However, I'm surprised you don't have a copy lying around. I keep just about *every* piece of software I've ever written just in case (with permission for work-for-hire stuff of course), even down to the Fortran assignments I did at Uni back in the early 80s.

That's a good habit to get into, although I'm starting to wonder whether I should perhaps free up some space by ditching the Fortran :-)

Comment: Yeah I am kind of disappointed in myself for that, but keep in mind that this was in the floppy-disk era.  Also I've moved countries since then :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things you can do to help them without the source code. You could apply an external manifest if the application will only work when it is elevated. You could advise them to install the application somewhere other than Program Files (generally an awful idea, but might work in this case.) You could apply a compatibility setting or teach them how to install it into "XP mode" so it runs in an XP virtual machine.

Failing all of those, you could offer to rewrite it in VB.NET so they would get a more modern ui, Windows 7 features (not just capabilities) and would actually own the source code for their app. That might have value for them.

And yes, you should have kept the code. I have CDs burned from my old projects going back to the dawn of time (at some point I copied things from 3.5" backups to CDs while I still had some machines that could do both) and I have made more than one previous client happy by sending them the CD. It is a really cheap marketing investment, really.

Comment: Manifests don't apply to 16-bit apps. And the access rights are not the issue anyway; the issue is that Win7 x64 doesn't support 16-bit applications at all, be they DOS or Win16.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is an application that is sold to customers, and is having trouble or doesn't work under Windows 7.

Consider advising the customer that the application should be:

- modernized, thereby easing the ability to add features/maintained
- otherwise run in XP Compatibility mode for their Windows 7 customers. Surely that number will only grow, and would become a support issue. Goto previous bullet.

Seriously though; your customer should realize that their software needs to be modernized. Hopefully you can persuade them of that long term goal; perhaps they already know that.

Comment: there's a reason I moved on back then :)  I had a hard time convincing them to move from DOS to Windows.